# Returning std::move(f) in std::for_each

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, std

I'm writing an implementation of standard c++ library for study.

The C++11 standard says that `for_each` returns `std::move(f)`.

```
template <class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);

Returns: std::move(f).
```

I thought that function scope local variable is move-constructed when it's returned.
Should I return `move(f)` explicitly?

Comment: In this case, returning `std::move(f)` is *nearly* equivalent to returning `f`. C++11 forbids the return value optimization for function parameters (but still allows implicit move for them). So the only difference, it seems to me, is that `return f;` falls back to a considering it as an lvalue if the rvalue would cause an overload ambiguity or would find no constructor. But `return move(f)` would fail with ill-formedness in such a case.

Comment: For example, the behavior would be different for a `Function` that is defined like this `struct Function { Function(Function&); };`. This class has no move constructor, and a copy constructor that does not accept rvalues. The `move(f)` return would therefor be ill-formed, while the `return f;` would be well-formed.

Comment: But then again, I'm not sure what the library constraints for function objects are. Perhaps they require `Function` to be copy initializable from rvalues. In which case there would indeed be no differences, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thx. `std::for_each` requires `Function` to be `MoveConstructible` but not `CopyConstructible`, so returning `move(f)` is used to force `Function` to be `MoveConstructible`. Checked with non-movable class and compile-error is occurred if I return `move(f)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Josuttis 's *The C++ Standard Library*

You don’t have to and should not move() return values. According to the language rules, the standard specifies that for the following code

```
X foo ()
{
X x;
...

return x;
}
```

the following behavior is guaranteed:

• If X has an accessible copy or move constructor, the compiler may
   choose to elide the copy. This is the so-called (named) *return value
   optimization ((N)RVO)*, which was specified even before C++11 and is
   supported by most compilers.

• Otherwise, if X has a move constructor, x is moved.

• Otherwise, if X has a copy constructor, x is copied.

• Otherwise, a compile-time error is emitted.

From **§25.2.4** (for_each)

> Requires:Function shall meet the requirements of *MoveConstructible
>   (Table 20)*. [Note:Function need not meet the requirements of
>   CopyConstructible (Table 21).—end note]

With `std::move(f)` you can be guaranteed of being able to read the mutated state externally.

Comment: I missed the requirement of `Function`. Thx.

Comment: However, the question asks about a function parameter "f" whereas the standard instead gives an example with a local variable.  Does RVO apply to function parameters?