# std::for_each seems to be cleaning std::string

Tags: c++, string, oop, foreach, stl

I'm making a simple snake game in c++17 with STL, and I have a problem with parsing board (std::vector) to std::string. I'm using std::for_each with my custom functor. Here's parsing method:

```
std::string Board::parseBoardToString()
{
    boardToString.resetStringBoard();
    std::for_each(v_board.begin(), v_board.end(), boardToString);
    return boardToString.getStringBoard();
}
```

Functor prototype (some of these method are for testing, doesn't matter):

```
class BoardToString
{
    public:
        BoardToString(unsigned _width);
        void operator()(char _cell);
        void resetStringBoard();
        std::string getStringBoard();
        void printStringBoard();
    private:
        bool isItLastLine();
        void resetCharsToNewLine();
        std::string stringBoard;
        const unsigned U_WIDTH;
        unsigned charsToNewLine;
};
```

And the operator() implementation:

```
void BoardToString::operator()(char _cell)
{
    stringBoard.push_back(_cell);
    //std::cout << _cell;
    //std::cout << stringBoard.back();
    if (isItLastLine())
    {
        stringBoard.push_back('\n');
        //std::cout << stringBoard.back();
        //std::cout << '\n';
        resetCharsToNewLine();
    }
}
```

After some tests I'm pretty sure that stringBoard gets cleared when for_each ends his job. GDB shows properly string size when for_each is working, and 0 after that. Both commented couts are working properly. Anyway I don't know why it goes like that. I know I could easily fix it by making a little bit different implementation, but I want to do it right way.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825552/passing-function-objects-into-std-algorithms-by-reference

Comment: If you used a lambda instead of `operator()`, you may have avoided the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
std::for_each(v_board.begin(), v_board.end(), boardToString);
```

to

```
std::for_each(v_board.begin(), v_board.end(), std::ref(boardToString));
```

Function objects passed to std algorithms are copied; std ref wraps them up so they are not copied.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that your functor object is being copied and the modifications are happening to the copy. This is why it seems to reset when you've finished.

You could change your functor to hold references to the variables you need to modify.

You could use a lambda instead, again holding references to the variables that need to be modified.

But to me the whole approach is too elaborate. Just write a for loop. Nothing gets copied, everything is transparent and direct.

Comment: std ref is easiest fix; pass `std::ref(boardToString)`.