# Changing an inlined global function to a constant propagated functor argument

Tags: c++, inline, functor, perfect-forwarding, compile-time-constant

I made a change to some code to increase user flexibility. However, this worsened performance in the original use cases. The original code made a call to a global function, and the new code made the global function a user-provided functor that defaults to the (now) global functor. I expected performance to be the same if the user used the default global functor, but that was not the case.

I will first present an outline of the original code and then explain the changes to produce the new code. `ImportantFunction` is the global function mentioned in the first paragraph above. Imagine `ImportantFunction` is something like `std::less<>`, `funcD` is something like `std::sort`, and `funcA`, `funcB`, and `funcC` are `std::sort`'s helper functions. **To keep the code clean, I am omitting additional function args for all of these functions.**  At first my code looked something like this:

```
void ImportantFunction(/*...*/){
    // ...
}

void funcA(){
    // ...
    ImportantFunction();
    // ...
}

void funcB(){
    // ...
    ImportantFunction();
    // ...
}

void funcC(){
    // ...
    funcA();
    // ...
    funcB();
    // ...
}

void funcD(/* non-functor args*/, /*Functor args*/){
    // ...
    funcC(/* ... */);
    // ...
}
```

The original code was fast and efficient. I then decided that the user should be able to provide their own definition of `ImportantFunction`. In accordance with [T.40](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rt-fo), I decided that `ImportantFunction` should be changed into a functor:

```
class DefaultImportantClass{
    [[gnu::always_inline]] constexpr inline void operator()(/* Important functions args*/) const {
        // ImportantFunction's body
    }
}
```

**In the cases that an `ImportantClass` object was a compile-time constant, such as is the case with a `DefaultImportantClass`, I wanted it to propagate through the code and have the same performance characteristics as if `ImportantClass`'s `operator()` were an inlined global function.** However, my testing shows that my new code did not perform as well as when I used `ImportantFunction`.

`funcD` takes several functor args. I do not know if the other functor args are constant propagated, but they are passed and forwarded the same way as important class.

```
template<typename ImportantFunctor = DefaultImportantClass>
constexpr inline void funcD( /* non-functor args passed by value*/, \
ImportantFunctor&& important_functor = DefaultImportantClass{},\
/* other functor args passed by r-value reference */) noexcept {
        
    // ...
    funcC(/* non-functor args passed by value*/, std::forward<ImportantFunctor>(important_functor), /* other functor args passed with std::forward /*);
}
```

`important_functor` is then passed around the exact same way in `funcA`, `funcB`, and `funcC`. As an example, I will show how `important_functor` is then called in `funcA`.

```
template<typename ImportantClass>
[[gnu::always_inline]] constexpr inline void funcA(ImportantClass&& important_functor){
    important_functor(/* args */);
}
```

To call `funcD` with the default functor, I just called

```
funcD(/* non-functor args */);
```

Any clue why my code is not performing as well as in the non-functor case?

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide a test where we can verify your claim - and then try to find the "flaws" and improve it. You could use https://quick-bench.com/ to set it up. Are you compiling with optimizations on?

Comment: The question is too general. You'll need to form a [mre] that actually demonstrates the issue. There is nothing obviously different except that the functions will need to pass one more argument which can obviously affect things like register allocation, etc. Note that all of your `inline` uses are unnecessary. `constexpr` implies `inline` and templates don't benefit from being declared `inline`. If you newly added `[[gnu::always_inline]]`, this is also not guaranteed to have a positive effect. You are making GCC ignore its own best guess. More generally the inlining decisions might differ.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I added the ```const``` and it did not make a difference in performance. I have updated the OP to include the ```const```, as you suggested. I will look into cleaning up the code to show benchmarks, but my hope is that I've done something obviously wrong with ```std::forward``` or made dumb assumptions about constant prop, since I don't know much about either.

Comment: Well, `std::forward<ImportantClass>` should be `std::forward<ImportantFunctor>`

Comment: @Bobby Constant propagation is irrelevant, assuming `DefaultImportantClass` does not have any data members that it accesses (which shouldn't be the case if it originally was a simple function). That `DefaultImportantClass::operator()` will be called is already encoded in the type of the expression. What value the object on which `operator()` is called has, is not relevant, at least if it is inlined so that the `this` pointer doesn't need to be passed (and even if the function is large enough that it is not inlined, passing an extra unused pointer shouldn't matter much, usually).

Comment: @TedLyngmo fixed, thanks

Comment: @user17732522 You are correct that ```DefaultImportantClass``` stores no data. It's only member is the operator function, like ```std::less<>```. "and even if the function is large enough that it is not inlined, passing an extra unused pointer shouldn't matter much, usually" ```DefaultImportantClass::operator()```  is called several hundred million times in my tests, and this change resulted in a 30% increase in the run-time of ```funcD```. So the smallest run-time change, such as an extra pointer being passed, may be noticeable in my tests.

Comment: @Bobby The point is that if the pointer passing is significant against the runtime of the function call, then the function should be small enough that it is inlined, especially if you are forcing it with always_inline anyway. If the function is large, then the relative impact of passing one extra unused pointer is insignificant, no matter how often the function is called. In the end this all depends on what exactly happens in these functions and what exactly the compiler decides to do. Most likely there is one specific hot loop in there that happens to get worse due to some minor detail.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the extra function argument, you can try passing by non-type template argument instead. That's of course less flexible for the user though and usually shouldn't be significant (the standard library also doesn't consider this "optimization").

Comment: @Bobby I can't tell. If the original didn't have any rvalue references, then (except for the new `important_functor` argument), there shouldn't be any reason for there to be other rvalue references in the modified version. That's completely orthogonal. Also `/* other functor args passed with std::forward /*` is wrong if these arguments are passed as actual rvalue references instead of forwarding references. `std::forward` must _only_ be used on forwarding references.

Comment: I can't tell from what you showed whether your pseudocode is just incomplete or not. In general there are multiple obvious errors, e.g. the call operator is `private`. That doesn't make it any easier to figure out what might be going on in your actual code.

Comment: @user17732522 What do you mean by "Only forwarding references should be forwarded with ```std::forward```"? I am modelling my code after the STL, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34829349/22764748) and its answers suggested that STL functors would have been better passed by r-value reference (&&). Other sample code I've seen suggested that r-value reference arguments (&&) should be passed along with ```std::forward```, so I am doing this by default. Will wrapping an r-value reference argument in ```std::forward``` ever hurt me?

Comment: @Bobby In the code your reference `important_functor` has a type of the form `T&&` where `T` is a template parameter of the function. Syntactically that's a rvalue reference, but it is also a _forwarding reference_ because it has this exact form for the type. If `T` was _not_ a template parameter of the function, then `T&&` would be still be syntactically a rvalue reference, but _not_ semantically a _forwarding reference_. Only _forwarding references_ should be forwarded and you are vague about these "other args" in your pseudo-code.

Comment: @Bobby "_Will wrapping an r-value reference argument in std::forward ever hurt me?_": Depends on how you are doing that. It is certainly an unintended use and may easily cause you mistakes by moving an object that shouldn't be moved. Also, you must of course be aware, that forwarding should happen _exactly_ once (or at least _at most_ once) in the function call execution, in the last use of the reference, otherwise you get wrong semantics.

Comment: oh, yes, these "other args" are also ```T&&```,  I just didn't include them in the template parameter list to keep the code clean. I use them exactly the same way as ```important_functor```, but the original implementation never had them as global functions, so if they aren't propagating correctly, I just haven't had the chance to notice.

Comment: @user17732522 ```funcC``` forwards twice, once to ```funcA``` and once to ```funcB```. Is that a problem? Also, what if ```funcC``` is called in a while loop in ```funcD```, forwarding each time?

Comment: @Bobby Yes, that means you are using a potentially-moved-from object in the call to `funcB`. You can only move/forward in the last use of the reference. That's whole concept of move semantics: Tell the last callee that you don't need the object anymore and that they can do with its state whatever they want.